# Change main screen of "SingleScreenApp" in React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm a newbie in React Native and I want to test `react-native-navigation` by [wix](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/)

I have a SingleScreenApp with a drawer. See below :

```
Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
  screen: {
    screen: 'example.HomeScreen', 
    title: 'Home', 
    navigatorStyle: {}, 
    navigatorButtons: {} 
  },
  drawer: {
    // optional, add this if you want a side menu drawer in your app
    left: {
      screen: 'example.LefMenu', 
      passProps: {}, 
      disableOpenGesture: false, 
      fixedWidth: 500 
    },
    style: {
      drawerShadow: true, 
      contentOverlayColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.25)', 
      leftDrawerWidth: 50, 
      rightDrawerWidth: 50 
    },
    type: 'MMDrawer', 
    animationType: 'door',
    disableOpenGesture: false 
  },
  passProps: {}, 
  animationType: 'slide-down' 
});
```

To have a menu-like behavior, I want to change the main screen of the SingleScreenApp (by clicking a button or other interaction).

I insist that I want to change/remplace the main screen, not pushing or showing a modal.

Should I start another SingleScreenApp with a root screen different screen ? Should I use "[resetTo](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=resettoparams)" method ?
What is the best in term of performance ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You do want to use [resetTo()](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=resettoparams). This will pop any currently-pushed screens and replace the current root screen with the new one.